# Enter value in Input text with description in another table

Tags: php, html, laravel

How do I update my `Extratos` table each time I edit the value in the input text.
In update Users I have Input text field and I would like each time to enter a numeric value also update in the `Extratos` table only the **`descricao`** and date, but only if there was a checkbox selected.

This update form go to table `users`

[image]

I need the insert that goes to this table `extratos`
I'm sorry I'm new to programming and I really need your help
[image]

```
<form action="/role-register-update/{{ $users->id }}" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Profit Division 5º Investment(week)</label>
        <input type="text" name="dindin9" value="{{ $users->dindin9 }}" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
</form>
```

```
public function registerupdate(Request $request, $id)
{
    $users = User::find($id);
    $users->dindin9 = $request->input('dindin9');
    $users->update();

    return redirect('/role-register')->with('status', 'User updated');
}
```

```
Route::put('/role-register-update/{id}', 'Admin\AdmDashboardController@registerupdate');
Route::get('/role-register', 'Admin\AdmDashboardController@registered');
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean, if the user table is updated, the `Extratos` table will be updated based on the user id?

if so, please try the method below:

```
public function registerupdate(Request $request, $id)
{
    $users = User::find($id);
    $users->dindin9 = $request->input('dindin9');

    if ($users->update()) {

        $user_id = $users->id;
        $extratos = Extratos::findOrFail($user_id);
        $extratos->descricao = $users->dindin9;
        $extratos->save();
    }

    return redirect('/role-register')->with('status', 'User updated');
}
```

hopefully answer your question

if you want create new record in extratos table, try this :

```
 public function registerupdate(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $users = User::find($id);
        $users->dindin9 = $request->input('dindin9');

        if ($users->update()) {

            $user_id = $users->id;
            $extratos = new Extratos();
            $extratos->user_id = $user_id;
            $extratos->descricao = $users->dindin9;
            $extratos->save();
        }

        return redirect('/role-register')->with('status', 'User updated');
    }
```

Comment: I really wanted to create a new record in the statements each time the input text had a value entered, but I will test your code and try to imprement it

Comment: I Give "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Extratos' not found"

Comment: I solved Error put on `use App\extratos;` but my extratos does not show what was edited

Comment: if you want create new record in extratos table..see my edited answer

Comment: Thanks again, it worked like a head shot, take me out of another doubt, how I would make this option register in the `extratos` table with only selected checkbox